# how to prevent buffer menu from folding

Tags: buffers, customize, menus

Is there a way to prevent emacs from folding the buffer menu?

Example, when I Control + 'right click' on a buffer I see a menu like this:

```
Buffer Menu
-----------
JavaScript >
XQuery >
Custom >
Others >
```

Sometimes, I have to look in under 2 or 3 submenus to find the file I'm looking for. I'd like just to see a list of all files, even if there are many.

I've tried customizing buffer menu but I did not see the option.

Comment: Consider using a more advanced option such as `M-x list-buffers` or `M-x ibuffer`  In addition, you can switch to buffers using tab-completion in the minibuffer which has an optional completions buffer to choose from various possibilities -- e.g., `M-x switch-to-buffer` or `M-x switch-to-buffer-other-window`.  Speedbar also has a nice buffer menu option, but the frames drove me crazy so I invested a few hours to remove the frame creation garbage from that library.

Comment: The built-in `bs` library also looks interesting:  `M-x bs-show`.  Alternatively, consider hacking `mouse-buffer-menu` to do whatever you want -- e.g., do *not* organize the buffers by groups.  Type `M-x find-function RET mouse-buffer-menu RET` to see what makes it tick -- it should be fairly easy to comment out the buffer grouping.

Comment: did you try control + "left click"? I have to add that in some versions and sometimes this menu shows properly to me... It's still a complete mystery to me how that menu is handled... I would really like to see an answer to your question! I would benefit from it myself too!